# Range of Colors to Represent Values

Tags: color-scheme

I have an application which draws a colorful bin, with different colors representing different values.

Originally (right side of image), I was using a scale which started with a lighter color, and kept getting darker until it reached a value of 0.  My end user said that it was too hard to distinguish between different shades of the same color.

So I switched to a scale from Yellow to Red (left side).  The end user agreed it was easier to distinguish, but notified me that Red is a reserved color (means emergency) and that I can't use it.

[image: Previous attempts]

I have tried looking at other color ranges (i.e. Purple to Blue, Yellow to Green), but I find it hard to extract any meaning from these (in the past darker meant less value).

Since there is always going to 5 different values (plus the 2 other colors for 'Unknown' and 'Initial'), I was thinking of using set colors for each value, but I think this would be even more confusing (i.e. what is Yellow vs Blue vs Green supposed to mean?)

Can anyone suggest a good color scheme or range to represent 5 values?

Comment: I've just found this tool: [ColorBrewer](http://www.personal.psu.edu/cab38/ColorBrewer/ColorBrewer_instructions.html). It allows you to choose the number of classes and the nature of your data, and will provide you with appropriate colour schemes.

Comment: So far I was using a tool called http://www.colorschemer.com/ for such kind of scenarios.

Comment: What is the objective? Is it to show discrete, specific ranges, or is it meant to show a broad, general spectrum?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've realised after writing this answer that @Brendon suggested the same in the [comments](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45156/range-of-colors-to-represent-values#comment68597_45156) - so I'm happy for any answer of his to take precendence.

You want [Colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/), its the most awesome set of visually distinguishable colours. Given the parameters you've suggested (7 sequential colours) you want something similar to the [YlGnBu pallette](http://colorbrewer2.org/?type=sequential&scheme=YlGnBu&n=7).

With my client I just pointed them to the site and got them to pick the pallette they liked the best.

N.B. For ages I missed the HEX mode in the 'pick a color system' for if you need to convert the colours into CSS hex values.

[image]

Comment: Nice link and useful link.

Answer (score 8):

I think you can get 5 distinctive enough colors that can impart the necessary notion of sequence or magnitude (lighter to darker):

[image]

It's a matter of mixing the colors in the Hue/Saturation/Brightness (HSB) color model using simple arithmetic. In the above example the top color (in HSB color model) is hue:60 saturation: 25% brightness: 100%.  Each successive (darker color) has a slightly different hue (increasing in number value), an increase in saturation and a decrease in brightness. The final bottom color is simply black.

Now you can take this image and plug it into a [color blindness simulator](http://www.color-blindness.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/) and see the magnitude implied by lightness to darkness is still very clear under all the simulated kinds of color blindness.

You can use this color scheme (#ffffbf #d2d982 #82993d #3d6614 #000000) or mix your own with any HSB color mixer, Photoshop or an [online HSB color mixer](http://www.color-blindness.com/color-name-hue/).

Answer (score 5):

This may be counter-intuitive at first and probably much harder to sell, but a grayscale color scheme may be a much better option, since [rainbow-based scales aren't that effective](http://blog.visual.ly/rainbow-color-scales/). The basic points from the article:

```
 - Colorblind people can't use them
 - The divisions between hues create edges in the visualization
 - The spectral order of hues has no inherent meaning
 - Yellow appears brighter than other colors
 - Detail is actually harder to see in a rainbow
```

Comment: I think the upshot of that article is to use 2 hues rather than 3, not necessarily to go grayscale.